# Samsung always returns null, but it works on HTC - findViewbyId

Tags: android, android-widget

I have strange problem, very strange. In xml I have

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_app_update">
    </Button>
```

and in code

```
btnV = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnV);
```

and on HTC it works but on Samsung I am getting null every time. Did anyone have similar problem ? I cleaned and restarted project and eclipse but nothing .

Comment: no, it is working fine with me in Samsung Galaxy Y

Comment: lolz...howz it possible?

Comment: Just refresh the project or Restart eclipse.

Comment: What does logcat say? Can you setContentView your xml layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem could be your custom background drawable.

Do these devices have different screen sizes or DPI? 
Do you have different drawables in drawable-ldpi and drawable-hdpi but not in the standard drawable folder?

Comment: Android will use the most appropriate drawables, if the correct ones aren't available, so I don't really understand why this answer is accepted.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html mentions:
However, if the only available resources are larger than the current screen, the system will not use them and your application will crash if no other resources match the device configuration (for example, if all layout resources are tagged with the xlarge qualifier, but the device is a normal-size screen). For more information about how the system selects resources, read How Android Finds the Best-matching Resource.

Answer (score 1):

This does sound very strange and normally I would have asked you to clean the project and possibly even restart Eclipse, but by the looks of it, you've already tried that.

How about renaming the ID of your `Button` view? Have you tried that?

Can you please show the part of your code where you initialize the layout and `Button`?